# How Can Calculators Display So Many Digits of PI?

Tags: floating-point, double, calculator, precision

I was playing around with the calculator on my phone and I discovered I can see arbitrary numbers of digits of pi on there. I know double precision floats only have accuracy up to ~16 digits so I figured anything past then would be gibberish, right?

It turns out it's able to display way more digits than 16, I'm talking **thousands** of digits.

I went to a website claiming to have the first million digits of pi https://www.piday.org/million/ and I checked to see if they lined up and surprisingly they did. I checked up to **700+** digits (*using ctrl+f to check if the sequence of digits exists*) and they still matched which doesn't seem possible with normal data types.

What kind of black magic are they using to pull this off? I checked with multiple sites claiming to have the digits of pi and they all also lined up. How is this possible?

Comment: "double precision floats only have accuracy up to ~16 digits": not correct. They only have accuracy up to ~16 *integer* digits. What happens after the decimal point is another matter entirely.

Comment: @user207421 So what happens after the decimal point?

Comment: A quick Google search [finds interesting discussions](https://www.reddit.com/r/explainlikeimfive/comments/ibk3yr/eli5_how_do_computers_calculate_pi_to_a_million/).  It looks like this rabbit hole might go pretty deep, which could arguably make this too broad.  Interesting for sure, but perhaps not as easily answered as one might hope.  (Unless someone knows enough about it to succinctly describe it, I could be overthinking the whole thing.)

Comment: @David Yeah I was looking into alternative data types but I find it hard to believe that the people behind the calculator on my phone would put in the effort to create/implement libraries that can handle arbitrary/extended precision. Plus it's running on a handheld device so there isn't much memory or cpu resources to dedicate towards storing and processing a completely unnecessary number of digits. Thanks for the link though, the rabbit hole is certainly deeper than I expected.

Comment: @chixken_tendies "double precision floats only have accuracy up to ~16 digits" --> Think _binary_.  `double` typically has 53 **binary** digits of precision with a _floating_ base-2 exponent.

Comment: Which phone, which calculator app, and how do you get it to display many digits?

Comment: Re "I find it hard to believe that the people behind the calculator on my phone would put in the effort to create/implement libraries that can handle arbitrary/extended precision.": There a numerous arbitrary-precision libraries available (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_arbitrary-precision_arithmetic_software), they likely use one of them (not necessarily from the list I linked to). And whatever "handheld device" you purchased within the last decade likely has plenty of memory and CPU resources -- computing a million digits of pi won't require more than a few MB of RAM.

Comment: @chtz Oh wow. I thought computing that many digits of pi would be rather computationally expensive. I guess I underestimated the power of the slabs we carry in our pockets nowadays.

Answer (score 1):

Amazon has numerous books that have the first million (or 5 million or 10 million) digits of pi.

According to https://www.livescience.com/record-number-of-pi-digits.html pi has been calculated to 62.8 trillion digits (presumably 2.pi.10^13). Don't try to buy that in book form.

To do these calculations you need an extended floating point representation. That might be using words of 64bit unsigned integers. You just need a lot of them, and to do all of the housekeeping to do stuff like carry propagation between the words.